# Problem installing SCTK 2.4.0 on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: compiling, gcc

I'm trying to install [SCTK 2.4.0](ftp://jaguar.ncsl.nist.gov/pub/sctk-2.4.0-20091110-0958.tar.bz2) on Ubuntu 13.10 with gcc 4.8.1 installed on my system but I get this error after I run "make all" command:

```
In file included from main.cpp:20:0:
recording.h:122:29: error: ‘Filter::Filter’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
         map<string, Filter::Filter*> filters;
                             ^
recording.h:122:36: error: template argument 2 is invalid
         map<string, Filter::Filter*> filters;
                                    ^
recording.h:122:36: error: template argument 4 is invalid
make[3]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/acl/Downloads/sctk-2.4.0/src/asclite/core'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/acl/Downloads/sctk-2.4.0/src/asclite'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/acl/Downloads/sctk-2.4.0/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What could I do to install this tool?

Answer (score 2):

Tried the following on 14.04:

Go to `recording.h` and `recording.cpp` files found under `sctk-2.4.0/src/asclite/core` and change all occurrences of `Filter::Filter*` to `::Filter*`

And try again, it should compile.

Answer (score 1):

The README says it was written in 2009. It also says it was tested and compiles on gcc version 4.3; you are using 4.8.1. It further states it was compiled on kernels as new as 2.6.19.

In Ubuntu 13.10, written in 2013, we are using kernel version 3.11-xx. The kernel has progressed too far and gcc has progressed too far to be able to successfully compile this antique. I suggest you look for a newer version to compile.